# Configuring Keystore/Truststore for 2-way SSL Java RMI in sandbox started from javaws

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, java-web-start

I'm trying to configure a Client/Server app after setting up 2-way SSL using the java SSLRMIClientSocketFactory and SSLRMIServerSocketFactory.  I know that to set the keystore and truststore on the client I need to set -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore and -Djavax.net.sslkeyStore.

The way I understand it Java web start downloads the jnlp and verifies the jar and launches the Client java application in a sandbox that then connects to the server application over RMI.  The problem is that when the application is run in this sandbox, the default truststore and keystore is not the same as what java web start uses.  Instead there is no default keystore and the default truststore is $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Is there a way to use the same truststore and keystore that javaws uses?  Ideally I would like to use the same trusted certs and client certs that the browser uses (and by extension javaws).  This way If the users configure their certificate through the Java Control Panel, then the application will use the same certificates.